# Can maven-antrun-plugin generate a HTML report showing the exception errors?

Tags: maven, surefire, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a Maven Surefire report that generates 3 files:

```
   TESTS-TestSuites.xml  - shows only passing tests. no info about fails or errors.
   TEST-me.qa.MyTest.xml - see below
   me.qa.MyTest.txt - file containing console output showing exceptions
```

Each failing test, shows an error in the **TEST-me.qa.MyTest.xml** file like this:

```
<testcase name="testIPcheckCanCalculate" classname="me.qa.TestLogChecks" time="0.016">
    <failure message="Average is too low: 0.5357142857142857. Min: 20.0" 
       type="java.lang.AssertionError">java.lang.AssertionError: Average is too low:
         0.5357142857142857. Min: 20.0
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at me.qa.TestLogChecks.testIPcheckCanCalculate(TestLogChecks.java:230)
</failure>
    <system-out>Testing InPreparer.getInv().getSomething().checkCanCalculate() ...
</system-out>
  </testcase>
```

Can maven-antrun-plugin generate a HTML report showing the exception errors (and fails) ?  Currently, the JUNit output file, called junit-noframes.html , only shows information in the **TESTS-TestSuites.xml** and so no failure information at all is being shown  (even though my include is for *.xml).  My workaround is to also look inside the **me.qa.MyTest.txt** file to see what the errors are, but I want those errors to appear on my report and also show a failed total number of tests on the report.

Here is my Maven config:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>test-reports</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <junitreport todir="target/surefire-reports">
                        <fileset dir="target/surefire-reports">
                          <include name="**/*.xml" />
                        </fileset>
                        <report format="frames" todir="target/surefire-reports" />
                    </junitreport>
        </tasks>
        </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-trax</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

OR, am I doing this all wrong and can Surefire itself generate a suitable report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.  Iinstead of using the maven-antrun-plugin I am now using the maven-surefire-report plugin along with the goal ***site maven-surefire:report*** .   NOTE: You need to run the **site** goal first in order to generate the CSS files for the report.

```
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showSuccess>false</showSuccess>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```